# python: how to make threads wait for specific response?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

could anyone please provide on how to achieve below scenario ?

2 queues - destination queue, response queue
thread picks task up from destination queue
finds out needs more details
submits new task to destination queue
waits for his request to be processed and result appear in response queue
or
monitors response queue for response to his task but does not actually pick any response so it is available to the other threads waiting for other responses ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a threads waits for a specific task completion, i.e it shouldn't pick any completed task except that one it put, you can use locks to wait for the task:

```
  def run(self):
    # get a task, do somethings, put a new task
    newTask.waitFor()
    ...
```

class Task:
  ...
  def waitFor(self):
    self._lock.acquire()

def complete(self):
    self._lock.release()

def failedToComplete(self, err):
    self._error = err
    self._lock.release()

This will help to avoid `time.sleep()`-s on response queue monitoring. Task completion errors handling should be considered here. But this is uncommon approach. Is it some specific algorithm where the thread which puts a new task, should wait for it? Even so, you can implement that logic into a Task class, and not in the thread that processes it. And why the thread picks a task from the destination queue and puts a new task back to the destination queue? If you have n steps of processing, you can use n queues for it. A group of threads serves the first queue, gets a task, processes it, puts the result (a new task) to the next queue. The group of final response-handler threads gets a response and sends it back to the client. The tasks encapsulate details concerning themselves, the threads don't distinguish a task from another. And there is not need to wait for a particular task.

Comment: let me give more details. there are 2 pairs of destination and response queues, and 2 group of threads. one is responsible for retrieving data and the other processes data BUT there might be a case where thread from processing group may require more data to be able to complete his task. So, it puts the request to the data destination queue and must get the right response otherwise it won't be able to process it correctly. access to the datasource must be limited therefore processing thread cannot acquire additional data on it's own. Does it make sense?

Comment: @m1k3y02 Yes, it does, thanks. In that case you should implement some `waitFor` method which locks and wait for the data and the processing thread should call that method after it puts the task back to the destination queue. Although it is not clear for me why not to divide processing into two steps: 1. get a task, do something, put to datagathering queue if additional data needed, and to response otherwise. 2. another threads monitor datagatheringqueue, process tasks, put them to responsequeue. But you might know the reason.

Comment: actually I was thinking about opening 1 thread for 1 task on the other hand splitting it might be more reasonable. Thank you :-)